# what is the area of △ABC?

Tags: geometry, contest-math, triangles, circles

In triangle ABC, let P and R be the feet of the perpendicular from A onto the external and internal bisectors of ∠ABC, respectively; and let Q and S be the feet of the perpendiculars from A onto the internal and external bisectors of ∠ACB, respectively. If PQ = 7, QR = 6 and RS = 8.

*I am not able to make a right figure.is there any simple way of solving this?*

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Are you sure of the order : P on external biss. and R internal biss. and Q on internal biss. and S external biss. ?

Comment: @JeanMarie yeah .Thats what the question says.

Comment: Almost surely, no simple way to solve this not-very-classical problem. Are you allowed coordinate geometry ?

Comment: @JeanMarie if required yes we can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

[image]

(image inserted by Jean Marie)

Let $A_2,B_2,C_2$ the half angles in $A,B,C$ resp.

P,Q,R,S are collinear. Here is why:

ARBP  is a rectangle ⇒ ∠PRB=∠PAB=B2 = ∠RBC  ⇒  PR||BC

A similar reasoning on  ASCQ gives RS||BC.

Line bissectors  BR  and  QC  meet at  I  ⇒  I  is the incenter of ABC.

Quadrilateral QARI  being cyclic :

∠QRI  =  ∠QAI = ∠QAC−∠IAC  =  90°−C2−A2 = B2  =  ∠RBC

Therefore : QR||BC

ARBP  is a rectangle ⇒AB=PR=13

AQCS  is a rectangle ⇒AC=QS=14

Let M, N be the resp. midpoints of [AB] and [AC].

By midpoint theorem,

$MN=\tfrac12 BC$
PM+MR=PQ+QR=13
⇒PM=MR=6.5

Similarly  QN=NS=7
MN=MR+QN−QR=7.5
⇒BC=15 ;

Knowing the three sidelengths : AB=13,  AC=14, BC=15, we can conclude that:

Area of ABC=64

Comment: Note that $APBR$ and $ASCQ$ are rectangles thus $PQ || BC$, $QS || BC$

Comment: how is ARBP a rectangle?

Comment: @AnanyaPathak since both ∠APB and ∠ARB are perpendicular

Comment: I have taken the liberty to insert a more accurate image of my own (done with GeoGebra). I have as well spaced certain of your lines. I wish you do not object.

Comment: @AnanyaPathak: They are rectangles because internal and external angles in a triangle are supplementary so half of them adds up to 90 degrees.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: There were many typos that I have corrected : 65 instead of 6.5, 12 instead of 1/2, $\angle RIB$ instead of $\angle RBC$, etc. (maybe you have typed this answer on a smartphone...)

Comment: Any comment ?...